# Passing JRuby objects to Java methods?

Tags: java, jruby

How can I pass a JRuby object (it's a quite simple object, containing a few fields of string and Hash type) to a method defined in a Java class?

UPD here is a serialized content of a type I need to share between JRuby and Java code:

`--- !ruby/object:LogStash::Event
cancelled: false
data: &1
  message: "q\r"
  '@version': '1'
  '@timestamp': 2015-02-17 12:10:17.695000000 Z
  type: human
accessors: !ruby/object:LogStash::Util::Accessors
  store: *1
  lut:
    type:
    - *1
    - type
    host:
    - *1
    - host`

The object is created by JRuby side. Ideally, I could access this object directly from Java and modify it. Less ideally, I need to convert it to something understandable by Java and then back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply specify an `Object` or `IRubyObject` argument signature in the method and it will work just fine when you call the Java method from your Ruby script ...

**UPDATE**: assuming a `LogStash::Event` you can either make the Java signature accept `(IRubyObject event)` and than use `event.callMethod("cancelled?").isTrue()` and similar on the Java side OR :

... if you mostly only need its `@data` on the Java side the internal Ruby Hash can be easily [retrieved](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/master/lib/logstash/event.rb#L156-L158) using: `event.to_hash` pass this to a Java signature accepting `(Map<String, ?> eventData)` you can easily retrieve `eventData.get("message")` and even update the data `eventData.put("message", 42)` it will be reflected on the Ruby side without additional work since Ruby hashes implement the Map interface and thus will be passed around without conversion (it will internally handle simple Ruby to Java string conversion and similar auto-magically)

otherwise (for sanity) I would recommend to introduce a simple bridge object that would wrap the event be passed into Java and handle the use-cases you need to invoke on the Java side.

Comment: your question is a little vague at this point - should have specified a complete use case ... essentially `IRubyObject` has an API e.g. `callMethod` you might need to keep a `Ruby` runtime instance (depending on how you started embed JRuby)

Comment: I'm calling Java code from JRuby application, not vice versa. I need to pass a Map object to that Java code so it can modify it.

Comment: just update your question with details - it simply should work if there's a Map type in the signature (Ruby Hash in JRuby implements Map)